# set integer value as bit mask

Tags: c

What is simplest way to assign a bit mask to integer value?
For example I want integer with first, third and forth bits = 1, other = 0.

Certainly I am looking for code, not for single value! And certainly there lot of possibilities, but I try to find simplest and most descriptive looking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best way to think (!) is to just index bits from 0, and then apply "to set the n:th bit, bitwise-OR with the value (1 << n)":

```
int first_third_and_fourth = (1 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 3);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want your code to be readable in terms of the bit numbers, something like this may be useful:

```
#define b0  0x0001
#define b1  0x0002
#define b2  0x0004
#define b3  0x0008
#define b4  0x0010
:
#define b15 0x8000

int mask = b3|b2|b0;
```

But, after a while you should be able to tell which hex values relate to which bits and you won't need mnemonic tricks like that:

```
int mask = 0x000d;
```

Comment: Exactly like I would have done it. Readable and clear. For a large project, having those #defines is common, so doing the mask with the bit ORs would be my choice for clarity down in the code.

Comment: WHy the arbitrary 16-bit formatting, though? And I would probably go for the macro notation, to get more semantics in there. Something like `#define BITMASK(n) (1 << (n))` maybe.

Comment: Arbitrary format because I stated "something _like_ ...". You can format it however you wish. As to why I didn't use macros, see my last para - after a while, you'll know these values off the top of your head :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the OR Bitwise operator (`|`) to combine bits:

```
#define FIRST_BIT (0x1)
#define SECOND_BIT (0x2)
#define THIRD_BIT (0x4)
#define FOURTH_BIT (0x8)
/* Increase by for each bit, *2 each time, 
   0x prefix means they're specified via a hex value */

int x = FIRST_BIT | THIRD_BIT | FOURTH_BIT;
```

And you can check if a bit is set using the AND Bitwise operator (`&`):

```
int isset = x&FIRST_BIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
int x = 0x0D;
```

And if you're lucky enough to use gcc and don't need to be portable:

```
int x = 0b1101;
```

Comment: Hmm. This answers the example question, but I'm guessing he wants a more general answer.  (of course, that's really just a guess, since there's not any detail...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online bit converter, if you don't want to do the sum yourself:

http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_unsigned_int.html

Just fill in the bits below (e.g. 1101), and compute the answer (e.g. 0x0000000D).
Any capable calculator should be able to do the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
int something = 0x00000001 * 2;
```

until you get to where you want.

Comment: You want `|` (bitwise or), not `&` (bitwise and).